# Applied texture is deformed or pixelated?

Tags: texturing, materials

Blender noob here. When I apply a texture to my model, sometimes it becomes deformed (circles 1 and 2) or pixelated (circle 3), and sometimes it works perfectly (circle 4). I've tried changing the face to a different texture and back to the desired texture, but it doesn't change anything. This issue persists in textured and rendered viewport shading, as well as in the final rendering.
[image: My problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying a texture to your object you have to properly uv-unwrap your object. You can do it by going into "Edit Mode" than hitting "U" on the keyboard and selecting "Unwrap" form the drop down menu.

With a complex model like yours a simple unwrap is not going to solve all of your issues.
So you should go get some more informations about uv-unwrapping from the Blender [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping) or other web tutorials.

Comment: I had unwrapped my model but hadn't thought to modify the UV map. Thank you!